# Jquery event handling order: click on ele: itself or parent first?

Tags: javascript

I have the following click event handlers:

```
 $('html').click(function() { do something});
 $('#my_div').click(function() { do something});
```

my_div is a descendant of html.

If I click on my_div, can I control which is called first? Can I depend on the my_div handler always being handled first?

Comment: I guess this practical working will give you better understanding,http://jsfiddle.net/fPxLm/

Comment: But is it ALWAYS like that?

Comment: yep, if you want to stop the event propagation from moving toward the higher order, then call this `event.stopPropagation()`. this way the call to child elements will remain only within the child scope itself.

Comment: Thanks. I do need to stop the propagation, but am doing it by setting a flag "clicked" and checking for it. event.stopPropagation() worked in Chrome. IE needed another solution and I never did get it to work in Firefox. The flag works :)

Comment: Are you working with IE browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Child event handler is always called before the parent event handler (event bubbling). So when you click `#my_div`, its click event handler is called. Here, you have the option to stop the event to bubble up to `html` click handler by using

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

i.e.

```
$('#my_div').click(function(event) { 
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note: when using jQuery, `event.stopPropagation()` may not work in all browsers. You will have to take `event` as an argument in your click handler

ie. `$('#my_div').click(function(event){ ... });`

Comment: I ended up handling event.stopPropagation by setting a "clicked" flag in the child, checking for this in the parent, and then setting it to not_clicked.